# LAME Conversion Without Extension

Tags: lame

I have a list audio file paths and extensions in a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Path        Extension  
~/src/0000  .wav
~/src/0001  .aif
~/src/0002  .wav
```

I need to run [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) on each file converting it to a standard format. The problem is LAME won't run on a source file without an extension. Is it possible to specify a file extension (as a parameter) without renaming the source file (renaming will be difficult in my case)? My current efforts yield:

```
> lame ~/src/0000 ~/dst/0000.mp3
Warning: unsupported audio format
```

Comment: What is the output of `file ~/src/0000`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true, `lame` can even read the input file from stdin if you give it `-` as a name.

Are you sure the input file is in the correct format? You can use the `file` util to check.

Have you read `lame` man page to see if some option is required for your input file?

Comment: I concur that `lame` can read stdin.

Comment: Thanks. I realized it was just my first WAV that had the issue and other files seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

There's another way without renaming the source file: create a symbolic link.

```
ln -s ~/src/0000 ~/tmp/0000.wav
lame ~/tmp/0000.wav ~/dest/0000.mp3
```